# JsonTextReader.ReadAsync not reacting on cancellation

Tags: rest, azure, json.net, async-await, office365

I am implementing an application that relies on [Office365 API Streaming Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-streaming-rest-operations#SubscribeToRichNotificationsBeta). When listening on subscriptions, I am reading the almost infinite result of a POST request. Practically I am getting a stream that contains a single JSON object, which starts with some warm-up properties and has an array of events. 
I am using the JsonTextReader to parse the stream. There is a `while (await jsonReader.ReadAsync(readCts.Token))...` loop that seamlessly parses the stream.

It is working just great... well, almost.
At predefined intervals, I get a KeepAlive notification. The reader is identifying them, thus I want to use this to reset the `readCts` CancellationTokenSource timeout. If the notification is not arriving at the time, the read operation should be canceled. So far so good. But timeout based canceling work only if the underlying network connection is healthy (simulated by setting the timeout less than the keepalive event interval).

After interrupting the connection, this async operation is hanging, the cancellation token has no effect over it. And the logical connection is lost as well, re-establishing physical one does not resume the stream.

I have tried setting HttpClient instance's timeout, but that had no any effect either. Finally, I managed it by setting `WinHttpHandler.ReceiveDataTimeout`. But for that, I am using a separate HttpClient instance.

1) Is the behavior of cancellation described above normal?
2) I know, that HttpClient instances should be reused. But in general API calls are not running for hours. And I will probably have several of such calls in parallel. Can I share one HttpClient instance, or do I need as many as parallel requests I have?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider other libraries for messaging? Maybe, RabbitMQ, or some other messaging? Maybe `Azure Function` subscribed on Office stream?

Comment: @VMAtm: As my data stream source is given, I have searched for something like the Graph API Client library, but I haven't found any. Interesting idea to put a middle tier in this message flow. But I think for now I can live with the workaround.

Regardless of this aspect, what is your opinion regarding the usage of one/multiple HttpClient instances in this scenario?

Comment: For my knowledge, same `HttpClient` in parallel is fine (we got near 1000 requests in second at the peak), but if you need to adjust the headers or token or something like that, a copy of client per type of settings do perform better.